# how to convert C# type parameter to Angular Typescript

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

I need to create parameter like it in Typescript in C# we do like it. I tried using typescript but I get issue.

I was struck with `Result<class1> modelObj=API_result;` code in typescript otherwise i created Model in typescript.

C#:

```
public class Result<T> {
    [JsonProperty("recordsTotal")]
    public int recordsTotal { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("recordsFiltered")]
    public int recordsFiltered { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public IEnumerable<T> data { get; set; }}
}
```

TypeScript:

```
export interface Result<T> {
  recordsTotal: number;
  recordsFiltered: number;
  data: T[];
}


export interface class1 {
  lng_id:number,
  str_name:string,

  //dtresult:DtResult[class1]
}
```

Convert to Angular TypeScript

Comment: What's wrong with this code ? Can you show an example of json which comes from C# ?

Comment: in c# Result<class1> modelObj = APIresult; but Typescript i don't know how to assign type Model  in typescript

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you keep the types the same on front- & back-end:

Typescript:

```
export interface Example<T extends Test> {
    data: T[];
}

export interface Test {
    lng_id: number;
    str_name: string;
}
```

C#:

```
public class Example<T> where T : Test
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Test // This could also be an inteface
{
    public int lng_id { get; set; }
    public string str_name { get; set; }
}


// Object returning to Front-end
var result = new Example<Test>()
{
    Data = new List<Test>() {
        new Test
        {
            lng_id = 1,
            str_name =  "Test"
        }
    }
};
```